# Web custom control with dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, custom-controls

I am trying to create a custom web control with a few controls on it, a textbox, label and dropdownlist, what I would like to do is add a property on the custom control to allow add select options on the dropdown list, the same way you would if it was just a normal dropdownlist i.e.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="normalddl" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="1st value" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="2nd value" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want a custom control that will look something like this (this is a simplified version)

```
<mycustomControl:ControlNamt ID="customddl" runat="server" >
   <asp:ListItem Text="1st value" Value="0"></asp:ListItem> -- how would I go about adding this in the custom control?
    <asp:ListItem Text="2nd value" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</mycustomControl:ControlNamt>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer you are looking for. Just a suggestion of how to achieve that by `UserControls`

**UserControl markup:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UC1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsScratch.UCTests.UC1" %>

<%-- Other controls here --%>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**UserControl code-behind:**

```
public partial class UC1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public IEnumerable<ListItem> DDLData;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    public override void DataBind()
    {
        ddl.DataSource = DDLData;
        ddl.DataBind();
        base.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**aspx page using that control (mark up; bare minimum)**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UCTests/UC1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="UC1" %>
...
...
<uc1:UC1 runat="server" ID="uc1" />
```

**Code behind of aspx page using that control**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uc1.DDLData = new []
        {
            new ListItem("1st Item", "0"),
            new ListItem("2nd Item", "1"),
            new ListItem("3rd Item", "2"),
        };
    uc1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm actually looking for a way to do it client side. without using any javascript.